# how to open and close dialog from a specific position?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

In my angular project i have a popup dialog open, the thing is i want the dialog to popup from the button and closes inside the button as this example shows : https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/dialog

**open from and close to**

How can i do it ?

This is my code, it just open the popup from the center of the page:

```
 dialogAdp() {
const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogAdpComponent, {
  width: 'auto',
  data: { incomplete: true },
  disableClose: true
});

dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
  this.iD = result;
});
  }
```

any help pls.

Answer (score 0):

Currently the MatDialog API doesn't expose any way to achieve this. The animations are not defined in their .scss files but in .ts files, so you won't be able to override it either. Your best bet would be creating your own custom Dialog using angular-cdk overlay (or you could try creating an issue on the material github, but odds of it being implemented any time soon would be slim).

There are different methods of creating custom overlay components, and the implementation is long so I won't dive into that here - but googling "cdk overlay dialog" should give you an idea of how this can be done.

Answer (score 0):

It was just out of curiosity, with this method you can achieve a similar effect like in You example:

```
const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(LoginDialogComponent, {
          width: '320px',
        });
        let center = (window.innerWidth / 2) - 160;
        let yu = 0
        dialogRef.updatePosition({left: '0px'})
        const interv = setInterval(() => {
          if (center > yu) {
            yu += 20;
            dialogRef.updatePosition({ left: (yu) + 'px' })
          } else {
            clearInterval(interv);
            center = window.innerWidth;
          }
        });

        dialogRef.beforeClosed().subscribe(() => {
          yu = 0
          const interv = setInterval(() => {
            if (center > 0) {
              yu -= 15;
              dialogRef.updatePosition({ right: (yu) + 'px' })
            } else {
              clearInterval(interv);
              center = window.innerWidth;
            }
          });
        })
```

Remove dialogRef.beforeClose from opne dialog metod,
and adding to close method in Dialog Component result is the same

```
onNoClick(): void {
    const elemRect = this.dialogRef._containerInstance['_elementRef']
    let yu = elemRect.nativeElement.offsetLeft;
    const interv = setInterval(() => {
      if (yu > - 160) {
        yu -= 10;
        this.dialogRef.updatePosition({ right: (yu) + 'px' })
        
      } else {
        clearInterval(interv);
        this.dialogRef.close();
      }
    });
  }
```

dialogref have updateSize option that is posible change dimension on close.
For Fun